# How do I index a certain character multiple times in a list of a list?

Tags: python, list, csv, slice

I am reading in numbers from a csv file and attempting to count each time the number '1' occurs in the first column of the file.

```
f = open(fileName, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)

votes = []
count = 0

for row in reader:
    votes.append(row)

for i in votes:
    if votes[0:i] == '1':
        count += 1

print(count)
```

This is the error i receive:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to understand the problem yourself first by thinking clearly about the intended logic, and making sure that you understand how the language works. In your own words, when you write `for i in votes`, what values do you expect `i` to have as a result? When you write `votes[0:i]`, what do you intend for that to mean? Why - i.e., in what circumstances - would the result of `votes[0:i]` be equal to `'1'`?

Comment: In plain English, what is your intended *algorithm* - the step-by-step approach to solving the problem?

Comment: Quite similar to your earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71655647/how-do-i-count-the-amount-of-occurrences-of-a-certain-value-in-a-column-of-a-csv where however your solution was more succinct and idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do this with a slice. If the first character in a line is `1` then `line[0] == 1` will be True.

You can simple sum the booleans by taking advantage of the fact that python treats `True` and `False` as `1`, and `0` allowing you to sum things like `sum([True, True, False, 0, 1])` which evaluates to `3`

Given a file at `path` like:

```
123
234
143

454
16786

111
```

You can simply do:

```
with open(path) as f:
    total = sum(l[0] == '1' for l in f)
    
print(total)
# prints: 4
```

Comment: how do i do it if i want to count different occurrences, for example '2', '3', '4', and '5', i tried changing the numbers and creating a new variable for each number but it does not work

Comment: If should work fine with different numbers. However, you can only loop over a file once (the above code loops over the file ). If you want to make more than one variable you should probably use a for loop or save the file to a list.

Comment: Ok, I have just posted another question with that gives you more context.